# Using "this" in static methods used to construct an object

Tags: c#, constructor, lambda, static-methods

This is what I mean.

I have a class with a constructor like so:

```
Class() : base(GetConstructorArgument1(), GetConstructorArgument2())
{
}
```

Because creating the arguments in the call to base, while possible, would be very cumbersome and gross. Both of those GetConstructorArgument methods are, by necessity, static.

GetConstructorArgument2() creates an array of lambdas. In those lambdas, I want to do work on "this", the object I am constructing.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If the class is static why do you need to use `this`?

Comment: `this` is not available in `static` functions because by definition, `static` functions are those that when invoked, do not receive `this` reference.

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob perhaps the class is not static? Why do you think it is?

Comment: Static methods do not take an implicit `this`, and you cannot even pass `this` explicitly, since it is not complete yet.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to address (not the mechanism)?  What you're wanting isn't possible, but there may be another option.

Comment: Please show how you expect to use `this` in lambdas will be created.

Comment: This kind of sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Can you give us a borader picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could be solved by giving this as an argument to the lambdas.  (If you can change the implementation in the base class.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These methods, by definition, have to run before `this` is constructed.  This is why they must be static methods.  As such, there is no real way to access `this` within them.

There really isn't a way to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

> Both of those GetConstructorArgument methods are, by necessity, static.
>
> I want to do work on "this", the object I am constructing.

You can't do both of these - if the methods are static, there is no `this` to work on.  Static methods belong to the class, not to the instance, so there's no instance to work with.